# Hyperlink to execute PHP

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, ajax

Below is code that will add a column called Printed to Gravity Forms and display a green or red dot representing if the form has been printed.

If the form has not been printed, I am trying to a) toggle the color b) print the page. How can I invoke both the PHP code to toggle and print the page?

```
add_action("gform_entries_column", "add_icon", 10, 5);
function add_icon($form_id, $field_id, $value, $lead, $query_string){

//targeting form 190 only.
if($form_id != 2)
    return;

//targeting field 5 only
if($field_id != "printed")
    return;

$lead_id = $lead['id'];

if($value == "Yes"){
    echo " <a onclick=\"var url='http://domain.ca/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/print-entry.php?fid=$form_id&lid=$lead_id&notes=1'; window.open (url,'printwindow');\" href=\"javascript:;\"><img src='" . GFCommon::get_base_url() . "/images/gf-percentbar-green.png' /></a>";
}
else{
    echo " <a onclick=\"var url='http://domain.ca/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_entries&id=2&lid=$lead_id&print=true'; window.location.href = url;\" href=\"javascript:;\"><img src='" . GFCommon::get_base_url() . "/images/gf-percentbar-red.png' /></a>";
    //echo " <a onclick=\"var url='http://domain.ca/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/print-entry.php?fid=$form_id&lid=$lead_id&notes=1'; window.open (url,'printwindow');\" href=\"javascript:;\"><img src='" . GFCommon::get_base_url() . "/images/gf-percentbar-red.png' /></a>";
}

// reset meta data for testing
//gform_update_meta($lead_id, "printed", "No");

 if (isset($_GET['print'])) {

    $print = $_GET['print'];
    $lid = $_GET['lid'];

    if ($print == "true") {

        gform_update_meta($lid, "printed", "Yes");

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome, unfortunately your question is either a PHP question or a plugin specific question. Both kinds are off-topic here. This site is mostly about questions relating to wordpress core API and functionality

Comment: You would want to use javascript for both of those actions, not PHP.